# Help with java regex

Tags: java, regex

Hey, I've been struggling with this regex and I'm out of ideas.
I have this types of strings (not all of them are here, but only this 2 types) and I have to extract the part between the ***th*** tags.

```
<th class="tip" title='manje'>manje</th>
<th class="tip" title='ne d.'>ne d.</th>
<th class="tip" title='manje'>manje</th>
<th class="tip" title='točno'>točno</th>
<th class="tip" title='više'>više</th>
<th class="tip" title='m./t.'>m./t.</th>
<th class="tip" title='v./t.'>v./t.</th>
<th class="tip">daje</th>
<th class="tip">X2</th>
<th class="tip">12</th>
```

I've tried some combinations bu I only get the value if there is no that attribute "title" in ***th*** tag.

This pattern only extracts the content if there is no "title" attribute in ***th*** tag:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<th class=\"tip\"[\\s*|[.]{0,20}]>(.*?)\\s*</th>");
```

This one also:

```
Pattern patternType = Pattern.compile("<th class=\"tip\"[\\s*|[.]{0,20}]>(.*?)\\s*</th>");
```

Any suggestions? Tnx

Comment: which one worked? score the one that did plz

Comment: Careful with the "[]", it defines a single character to be matched.  I'm not sure what it is actually trying to match for "[.]".

Comment: It would probably be more appropriate to use the dom and sax utilities anyway since you are reading XML.  Those are part of the Java SE base packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<th class=\"tip\"[^>]*>(.*)</th>");
```

Comment: Woohoo :D this one workes for me. Tnx. Good idea with matching until ">".

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions are not suitable in all cases. Use Jsoup instead:

```
package so6235727;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class PrintContent {

  private static final String html = //
      "<th class=\"tip\" title='manje'>manje</th>\r\n" + //
      "<th class=\"tip\" title='ne d.'>ne d.</th>\r\n" + //
      "<th class=\"tip\" title='manje'>manje</th>\r\n" + //
      "<th class=\"tip\" title='točno'>točno</th>\r\n" + //
      "<th class=\"tip\" title='više'>više</th>\r\n" + //
      "<th class=\"tip\" title='m./t.'>m./t.</th>\r\n" + //
      "<th class=\"tip\" title='v./t.'>v./t.</th>\r\n" + //
      "<th class=\"tip\">daje</th>\r\n" + //
      "<th class=\"tip\">X2</th>\r\n" + //
      "<th class=\"tip\">12</th>\r\n";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document jsoup = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements headings = jsoup.select("th.tip");
    for (Element element : headings) {
      System.out.println(element.text());
    }
  }
}
```

See how easy this is?

Comment: Yes, but I have a really big HTML page that I have to parse and regex where my first hint. But this tool looks really great. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<th[^>]*>(.*?)\\s*</th>");
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work for me. stuken.yuri's regex works. tnx anyway

Answer (score 0):

What the heck, one more Pattern answer attempt, this one with look ahead and look behind:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=<th .{0,100}>).*(?=</th>)");
```

**EDIT 1**
Regarding `I tried it and it doesn't work in any case`: perhaps your harness is different from mine:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Foo1 {
   private static final String FOO_TXT = "Foo1.txt";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=<th .{0,100}>).*(?=</th>)");

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(Foo1.class.getResourceAsStream(FOO_TXT));
      while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = scan.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Line: " + line);
         Matcher match = pattern.matcher(line);
         if (match.find()) {
            System.out.println("Match: " + match.group());
         } else {
            System.out.println("No match found");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This assumes that the text file is named Foo1.txt and that it is located with the class files.

Comment: Weird... your pattern really does not work on my machine and the other ones do.  (I removed my comment saying it does not work.  My harness is different, but I don't see what difference it might do on the matches...)

Comment: If I change your lookahead stuff ("(?<=") with a simpler non-matching group tag ("(?:") it does work.

Comment: @toto: perhaps if you edited your original post and showed us your test harness, preferably as a small compilable and runnable program, I could better see why my regex fails for you.

Comment: I put my code as an answer (unfortunately).  I have to run now, but I'll check tonight to see if you have any comment.  I'm running Java 7 (beta) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm including my test code because it seems I have positive/negative matches when others have negative/positive matches.

```
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

public static void test(String patternString) {
    System.out.println("Test with pattern: " + patternString);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    String[] testStrings = {"<th class=\"tip\" title='manje'>manje</th>", "<th class=\"tip\">daje</th>"};
    for (String testString : testStrings) {
        System.out.println("> Test on " + testString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(">> number of matches in group = " + matcher.groupCount());
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println(">>group " + i + " is " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(">> no match");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("<th class=\"tip\"[\\s*|[.]{0,20}]>(.*?)\\s*</th>"); // op
    test("<th[^>]*>(.*?)\\s*</th>"); // Billy Moon
    test("<th class=\"tip\"[^>]*>(.*)</th>"); // stuken.yuri
    test("(?<=<th .{0,100}>).*(?=</th>)"); // Hovercraft full of Eels
    test("(?:<th .{0,100}>).*(?:</th>)");
}
}
```

My output is that I get a match for Billy Moon and stuken.yuri, but no match for the OP or Hovercraft.   I would be curious to see if others get the same.  I am using Java 7 beta with Windows 7.